# Get and process the last word of each line while looping through lines of text

Tags: bash

So, let's say I have got this data file:

```
apples   asd   45      321     7000
oranges   gl   78      102     850
some    ltd     83      15      500
other   nova    80      50      3500
stuff    600     65      115     450
```

And I want to loop through each line, get the last word (which is the big numbers), which is supposedly the price. Then check if it's smaller than `1000`, and if so - output it to another file.

Here's what I've got:

```
touch items_cheaper_than_1k.txt
while read LINE
do
        PRICE="$(cut -d. -f3 $LINE)"
        if [$PRICE < 1000]; then
                $LINE >> items_cheaper_than_1k.txt
        fi
done < cars.txt
cat items_cheaper_than_1k.txt
```

The problem is that I get the error

```
cut: apples: No such file or directory
cut: asd: No such file or directory
cut: 45: No such file or directory
cut: 321: No such file or directory
cut: 7000: No such file or directory
```

(and sequentially for each single word of each line). Am I doing the cut wrong?

After the list of errors per line, I get `line 5: 1000]: No such file or directory`

Comment: The argument to `cut` is a filename, not a string to process. You need to pipe the string to `cut`.

Comment: You also need to learn basic shell syntax. `if [$PRICE < 1000]` should be `if [ $PRICE -lt 1000 ]`. You need spaces around `[` and `]`, you have to use `-lt` because `<` is the shell's input redirection operator. And `$LINE >>` should be `echo $LINE >>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$NF<1000' file.txt
```

`$NF` is the value of the last field and `$NF<1000` checks if the value is less than 1000, if so then the line is printed.

To save the output in another file e.g. `out.txt`:

```
awk '$NF<1000' file.txt >out.txt
```

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt 
apples   asd   45      321     7000
oranges   gl   78      102     850
some    ltd     83      15      500
other   nova    80      50      3500
stuff    600     65      115     450

% awk '$NF<1000' file.txt
oranges   gl   78      102     850
some    ltd     83      15      500
stuff    600     65      115     450
```

Comment: LOL, that's like 9999 times easier and faster than my approach of writing a whole script! The power of knowing the commands...

Comment: @Milkncookiez Yes. `awk` is the _go-to_ tool for any field separated data.